# Cycle detection with the tricolor algorithm vs using a set - any advantage in using one of them over the other?

Tags: algorithm, graph, depth-first-search

There are these two seemingly similar approaches to detect a cycle in a graph:

1. Traverse the graph, DFS style, assuming all nodes are white until you visit them for the first time, making them gray. After all processing is done on the node, you turn it to black. If you ever visit a gray node, you know you have a cycle.
2. Traverse the graph, DFS style, and keep a set S with all the nodes currently in your DFS stack (just for performance purposes). Every time you visit a node, you add it to S, and every time you are done with a node, you remove it from S. A cycle exists if at any point you attempt to visit a node that is already in S.

Is there any practical advantage in choosing one of the alternatives over the other? Some kind of trade-off I may be missing? Or using one or the other leads to exactly the same?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two are conceptually equivalent: the set `S` contains exactly the gray nodes, and the algorithms are the same otherwise.

In practice however, there are subtle differences:

- If the set `S` is a hash-based implementation, then the nodes must be hashable. If the hash function is poorly-designed, or the data is chosen adversarially, then performance can suffer.
- If the set `S` is a tree-based implementation, then the nodes must be comparable. Additionally, you no longer have (amortized) constant-time set lookup.
- If colors are used, then the nodes must have a "color" field that isn't being used for another purpose. However, this gives the fastest "set lookup" since it's just one lookup/comparison.
- If the graph is directed or disconnected, then you will have to DFS multiple times (from all white nodes). Keeping track of whether a node has been visited requires a second set, since the first set is always empty at the end of DFS. Because there are actually 3 node "states", 2 sets are required to store that information.

In performance-critical situations, the color approach will have smaller constant factors for the linear runtime. But if adding a `color` field to the nodes is not an option, then using sets is a fine alternative. If nodes are currently implemented as `int`s or `String`s (as opposed to a `Node` class with the possibility of adding fields), then the set approach will be easier to code, since you can avoid changing representation of nodes.